# JQUERY .each how to reach array within object?

Tags: javascript, json, object, jquery

I have JSON data which I get with an ajax function,
I loop through this data using a each function like this :

```
                    $.each(data, function (index, trip) {
                    // trip contains data
                    console.log(trip);
                    
                    content += '<article class="tripPreview">';
                    content += '<span class="tripTitle">'+trip.title+ '</span>';
                    content += '<div class="tripOverlay">'+trip.description+ '</div>';
                    content += '<img src="public/uploads/tripphoto/'+ trip.id +'/'+trip.tripphotos.filename+'">';   
                    content += '</article>';        
                    
                });
```

How do I reach `tripphotos > filename > thumb > url` ?

#### JSON:

> `{"created_at":"2012-12-06T13:02:03Z","description":"test","id":11,"province":"Friesland","range_high":null,"range_low":null,"start_city":"Leeuwarden","title":"test","updated_at":"2012-12-06T13:02:06Z","user_id":1,"views":1,"categories":[{"ar_association_key_name":"4","created_at":"2012-12-04T13:12:43Z","id":2,"name":"Urban","updated_at":"2012-12-04T13:12:43Z"}],"tripphotos":[{"created_at":"2012-12-06T13:02:05Z","filename":{"url":"/uploads/tripphoto/filename/2/1280x1024-colour-wood-flip.jpg","thumb":{"url":"/uploads/tripphoto/filename/2/thumb_1280x1024-colour-wood-flip.jpg"}},"id":2,"trip_id":11,"updated_at":"2012-12-06T13:02:05Z"}]}`

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do, and why your current approach isn't working? Also, can you post the original JSON string that you're parsing? What you've posted looks like it's copied out of the developer tools console of a browser after calling console.log on the object? The trouble is that doesn't expand objects to show you all their properties.

Comment: `trip.tripphotos[0].filename.thumb.url` That's an array ?

Comment: Change `console.log(trip)` to `console.log(JSON.stringify(trip))` and paste what you get, so we can know what the structure of your trip object is.

Comment: Ive added the whole object stringyfied, Iam trying to show the image to the user in the each like this <img src="filenamefromjsonobjecthere/> this doesn't work in the each trip.tripphotos.filename.url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your JSON, it looks like `tripphotos` is an array, so you'll need another `each`:

```
$.each(data, function (index, trip) {
   ...
   $.each(trip.tripphotos,function(index2,tripphoto){
      console.log(tripphoto.filename.thumb.url);
   });
});
```

Unless you know there will only ever be one (or, you're after just the first):

```
$.each(data, function (index, trip) {
    ...
    console.log(trip.tripphotos[0].filename.thumb.url);

});
```